# Convert JSON full with object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I have JSON which is structured like

```
{
  "Items": [
    {
      "id": {
        "N": "3"
      },
      "msg": {
        "S": "qdfgqdfg"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": {
        "N": "2"
      },
      "msg": {
        "S": "sdfsdf"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": {
        "N": "4"
      },
      "autre": {
        "S": "bobobqfg"
      },
      "msg": {
        "S": "srgshjsf"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": {
        "N": "1"
      },
      "msg": {
        "S": "test"
      }
    }
  ],
  "Count": 4,
  "ScannedCount": 4
}
```

I would like to convert this to select `id` and `msg` and display them.

I try this :

```
var parsed = JSON.parse(test);
alert(parsed);
```

but this return only `[object Object]`

I use Firefox console and see the array structure this is full of the object.
[image]

Comment: When you use `alert()` it internally calls `.toString()` on whatever is passed to it, hence why you're getting `[object Object]`

Comment: `parsed` does hold the object... Access the respective property...

Comment: You parsed a JSON to object and you got an object. What is the problem?

Comment: `alert` displays string or other types converted to string. Objects are converted to string as "[object Object]".

Comment: use console.log and you will get what you need\

Comment: `alert` doesn't "return" anything. It "displays" string representations of things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through your data and access using `key` `value`

```js
var data = {
  "Items": [
    {
      "id": {
        "N": "3"
      },
      "msg": {
        "S": "qdfgqdfg"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": {
        "N": "2"
      },
      "msg": {
        "S": "sdfsdf"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": {
        "N": "4"
      },
      "autre": {
        "S": "bobobqfg"
      },
      "msg": {
        "S": "srgshjsf"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": {
        "N": "1"
      },
      "msg": {
        "S": "test"
      }
    }
  ],
  "Count": 4,
  "ScannedCount": 4
}

for ( var i =0; i< data.Items.length; i++){
 console.log(data.Items[i].id.N);
  console.log(data.Items[i].msg.S);

}
```

Comment: i updated my answer with **for loop**. Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 1):

As you see, it is an object. So, you should access the property like the following:

```
id0 = parsed.Items[0].id; // access to the id of the first element of the list
msg0 = parsed.Items[0].msg; // access to the msg of the first element of the list
```

Also, you can loop through the items using the following code:

```
for ( var i =0; i< data.Items.length; i++)
{
    console.log(data.Items[i].id.N);
    console.log(data.Items[i].msg.S);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Firefox you can use

```
alert(parsed.toSource());
```

if you want to see your object in alert message. This would be enough for debugging purposes. Otherwise use console.
Converting JSON string to object is done correct from your side